# Need help structuring an Angular app

Tags: angularjs

I have a basic angular app, users can post `Adverts`, now I am working on how to search / filter for adverts. I am currently using a filter like so..

`<a data-ng-repeat="advert in filtered = (adverts | filter:filterBySearch) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" data-ng-href="#!/adverts/{{advert._id}}" class="list-group-item">`

where I have created my own fiter, `filterBySearch`

I also have a range slider for filtering by a range of prices, and I have all this working with pagination.

My concern is because I have declared `<section data-ng-controller="AdvertsController">` at the top of the homepage in order to use the `AdvertsController` for `Advert` logic, I am now finding I am putting logic in here around, pagination, the range slider, filtering logic etc. I would like to know how best to split this logic out into their own controllers or whatever it needs.

Answer (score 1):

The controller should not he hadling such complex business logics in itself. It must be used for binding scope elements, handling events, updating states etc. I would suggest pulling your pagination, range slider, filtering logics etc in dedicated `angular service` and inject the it into your `AdvertsController`. This way you can also utilize them in any other view/controller you require.

Read more about modularity in AngularJS [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

Answer (score 0):

If you have business logic pertaining to elements inside of your  tag, then it still makes sense to have all of your code inside of that controller.  It might make more sense to rename your Controller to something that better suits your needs.